„Es ist mir interessant" vs „Ich finde es interessant": wann kann man den Dativ benutzen?
Ich habe vor kurzem in einem Aufsatz

Es ist mir interessant...

geschrieben.  Man hat das korrigiert und gesagt, dass ich lieber

Ich finde es interessant...

hätte schreiben sollen.
Gibt es einen Unterschied?  Kann man den Dativ mit Adjektiven so verwenden?  Ich denke schon, z.B. „es ist mir egal".
Übrigens, kann man den Dativ so verwenden, „Mir wurde etwas korrigiert", um zu zeigen, dass etwas mich persönlich betrifft?  So etwas darf man auf Spanisch machen.

Im Prinzip geht das, es ist nicht falsch und auch verständlich.
Es ist aber mit den meisten Adjektiven und Adverben nicht üblich.
Daher empfehle ich dir, diese Konstruktion nur so zu verwenden, wie du sie von Muttersprachlern hörst. Ansonsten klingst du wie ein etwas kauziger Kunsthistoriker, der anlässlich der Betrachtung eines Biedermeiermöbels plötzlich anfängt zu sprechen wie eine Person aus einem Stück von Gerhard Hauptmann.


Mir wurde etwas korrigiert.

Das kannst du so sagen. Klingt aber auch wieder ein bisschen seltsam. Ich würde Schweizerdeutsch vermuten.

Ja, entweder Schweizerdeutsch - oder Passiv.

Man könnte auf die Verbesserung von

Es ist mir interessant ...

natürlich antworten:

Das ist mir egal.

Tatsächlich gibt es diese Wendung (sie nennt sich "Dativus iudicantis"), aber in der Form, in der sie in dem Beispiel gebraucht wurde, ist sie zumindest ungebräuchlich.
Der Grund, warum das verbessert wurde, ist vermutlich darin zu suchen: jemand, der gerade eine Sprache lernt, begibt sich mit der Verwendung solcher Konstruktionen auf dünnes Eis, das selbst einem Muttersprachler zum Verhängnis werden kann.

Ich glaube nicht, dass "Das ist mir egal." die Antwort des OP auf die Korrektur war, sondern ein Beispiel, in dem der Dativ verwendet wurde.

@O.R.Mapper: Ich dachte eigentlich, mit der Verwendung von könnte, also des Konjunktivs, ausreichend angezeigt zu haben, daß es sich dabei um eine mögliche und nicht die tatsächliche Antwort des OP handelt.

Verstehe. Ich las das als "man könnte" = "andere, ggf. der OP, machen es vielleicht, aber ich empfehle, eher zu überlegen, wieso die Korrektur vielleicht doch berechtigt ist".

@O.R.Mapper: Man könnte deshalb so darauf antworten, weil "Es ist mir egal." dieselbe Konstruktion wie "Es ist mir interessant." wäre - nur, daß in diesem Falle nichts ungewöhnlich und deshalb verbesserungsbedürftig erschiene. Das ist eine in der deutschen Sprache äußerst unidiomatische Konstruktion und nennt sich "Ironie".

Der Vorschlag deines Korrektors klingt besser, aber auch korrekt und viel näher an deinem Versuch ist

Es ist für mich interessant...



Gibt es einen Unterschied? Kann man den Dativ mit Adjektiven so verwenden? Ich denke schon, z.B. „es ist mir egal".

Bei "egal" geht das, bei "interessant" klingt es sehr seltsam, ich kann dir aber nicht sagen warum.


Übrigens, kann man den Dativ so verwenden, „Mir wurde etwas korrigiert", um zu zeigen, dass etwas mich persönlich betrifft? So etwas darf man auf Spanisch machen.

Ja, in dieser Situation klingt das sogar sehr gut.

"Es ist mir interessant" ist zwar strukturell analog zu "Es ist mir egal", wird aber nicht benutzt. Aus Muttersprachler aus dem Westen Deutschlands habe ich diesen Ausdruck in meinem ganzen Leben noch nie in Gebrauch gehört.
Ob er korrekt ist, ist eine eher philosophische Frage: Wird Korrektheit durch theoretische Regeln definiert oder durch den praktischen Gebrauch?
Mein Rat: Orientiere dich am praktischen Gebrauch, vergiss "Es ist mir interessant" und benutze "Ich finde es interessant".

Wenn "Korrektheit durch praktischen Gebrauch" (im ausschließlichen Gegensatz zu "theoretischen Regeln") definiert würde, dann wären "komm zu misch zurück" und "ich liebe dia" korrekte hochdeutsche Formulierungen, i schwör! Um es mit Karl Kraus zu sagen: "Von Rache sprech’ ich, will die Sprache rächen, an allen jenen, die die Sprache sprechen." (aus "Bekenntnis", 1916)

@bakunin Das Spektrum der deutschen Sprache ist sehr breit, besonders durch die Vielzahl an Dialekten. Und in bestimmten Nischen in diesem Spektrum werden Sätze wie deine Beispiele real benutzt und von anderen Teilnehmern dieser Nische als normal angesehen. Aber diese Nische heißt nicht "hochdeutsch". Und um auf die Frage des OP zurückzukommen: ich kenne persönlich keine Nische, in der ein Muttersprachler "Es ist mir interessant" verwendet.

Ich habe es in meiner Antwort verlinkt und erwähne es gerne noch einmal: die Konstruktion heißt "Dativus iudicantis" (Dativ des Urteilens) und die gibt es nicht erst seit althochdeutschen Zeiten, sondern selbst im Gotischen. Zum Argument "hab ich noch nicht gehört" sage ich nur: es gibt Dinge zwischen Himmel und Erde, von denen sich eure Schulweisheit nichts träumen läßt.
